# Is "the clock came alive" the opposite of "the clock went dead"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-request

One of the meanings of the adjective "[dead](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dead_1?q=dead)" is having no power/electricity/battery.

But I don't see the opposite adjective "alive" meaning having power/electricity/battery.

We can say "**the clock went dead**".

Can we say "**I put the battery in and the clock came alive**"?

Comment: 'Alive' is actually quite common when talking about electricity. Don't touch that wire! It might be alive! Or 'live', and **yes**, you can say that the clock _came alive, came back to life, was restored to life, was revived, etc_, when you replaced the battery.

Comment: But _started_ might be more usual.